# Connect to one firebase project with multiple android applications

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

You are my only hope solving this problem. I have 1 firebase project, and two android applications, one is for the users, and one is for the coaches. I store data in firebase firestore, and my plan is the coaches can upload trainings to firestore and that list appears on the users app, the users then can sign up for training etc etc...but with the second application connected to the firebase project, this error pops up in both applications:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process [package name]. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I have found some infos on internet that says I must use FirebaseOptions.Builder() to initialise one-one separate FirebaseApp instance in each android app, but I tried it and didnt work. This was the code for it:

```
private fun firebaseInit() {
        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId("qrtrainertruck-adminapp")
            .setApplicationId("1:221722591872:android:b3964eb554e10b6251dc65")
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyCfjNCD5kHb-LnB5FZXKPxi1t0lXJQASB4")
            .build()

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "adminapp")
    }
```

Maybe just the api key is wrong, or I dont know...If this is the solution then where can I find these attributes (projectId, ApplicationId, ApiKey) for the function?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Have you added the apps on the firebase console? I believe you just need to add apps on the console and put the provided json in the app

Comment: You don't need to initialize with hard-coded values unless you want to. If you don't, all that matters is that: 1) both Android apps are also registered in your Firebase console, and each has a unique package name, 2) you download an up to date `google-services.json` from the Firebase console, so that it contains the definitions of those apps, 3) You then use this up to date `google-services.json` file in both of your apps. Did you take each of these steps?

Comment: yes, I have added both apps to firebase project and updated the json file as well

Comment: So have you followed the exact steps Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment and you get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both apps are part of the firebase project, both have unique package name and the updated json files are in the apps "app" folder

Comment: In the json files, the two apps have the same api key. Maybe thats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple apps in one firebase project.